# Smart Sheet Row calls not getting information or working

Tags: python, smartsheet-api

I'm trying to use the row attribute created_by accessing it with the Python SDK and it keeps throwing an error. I'm not sure if I'm missing something.

Every time I try to use it I get the error:

```
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\smartsheet\models\row.py", line 166, in __getattr__  raise AttributeError(key)
  AttributeError: created_by
```

It also doesn't return anything when I run created_at, but at least it doesn't throw an error.

Anyone else have this problem, or at least can point me to what I'm doing wrong?

It happens ever time I call it. Here is a simple example

```
smartsheet = smartsheet.Smartsheet(SMARTSHEET_ACCESS_TOKEN)
sheet = smartsheet.Sheets.get_sheet(IT_TRACKER_ID)
rows = sheet.rows
columns = sheet.columns

print rows[1].created_by
```

Comment: Can you please update your question/post to include your code that is calling a function in the Python SDK and then trying to access the **created_by** attribute?   Seeing the code that's producing the error you've described will allow folks to reproduce and troubleshoot the error.

Comment: I added a code sample. am I just using it incorrectly? Its in nothing complicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Via the API, if you want the **Get Sheet** response to include the **createdBy** attribute for each Row, you must specify the **include** parameter on the request with a value that includes the string **rowWriterInfo**. (See the [Row Include Flags](http://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/?python#row-include-flags) section API docs for more info.) For example:

```
GET https://api.smartsheet.com/2.0/sheets/7359436428732292?include=rowWriterInfo
```

If I execute this request via Postman, I see that the response does indeed include the **createdBy** attribute for each Row object in the response.

Via the SDK, I can execute this same request as follows:

```
sheet = smartsheet.Sheets.get_sheet(7359436428732292, include='rowWriterInfo')
```

So, the SDK seems to be sending the request properly. However, it doesn't look like the SDK currently supports accessing the **created_by** property of Row objects -- if you search the *Lib\site-packages\smartsheet\models\row.py* file for *created_by*, you'll come up empty.

I'd suggest that you report this issue to Smartsheet by opening an issue in the [corresponding GitHub repo](https://github.com/smartsheet-platform/smartsheet-python-sdk/issues). In the meantime, you might consider updating your local copy of the Python SDK to add support for accessing the **created_by** property of Row objects.

Comment: Great thanks!  I looked in the row.py file and when I didn't see the created_by I thought I was missing something. I guess I'll have to write my own to fetch the created_by.  Odd they don't have it, it seems like it could be a useful piece of information when writing scripts.